# facebook oauth authentication doesn't return "code" parameter

Tags: facebook, api, oauth, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to use facebook's oauth.
Basically facebook has to return me a "code" parameter.
But i get nothing, it just return my callback url (to the exact same url).

i'm generating this url with my app.

http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=76209388873&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Ffb.lous%2Fmain%2Ffacebook_callback&scope=read_stream

I used other parameters and options, just when i set response_type=token
i get parameter list for javascript (with # character instead of ?, its for client side, i'm trying to write some api bot)

So right now i can't get any parameter with someway.

Comment: Maybe facebook blocked Fblous.

Comment: Almost after 2 years I stumble with the same problem. Got any fix? Would be a great help.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to solve exactly the same thing for several hours. In my case it turned out to be a stupid redirect problem. Facebook correctly redirected back to http://www.mysite.com with the code parameter, then my webapp redirected to http://www.mysite.com/users/login (because the user wasn't logged in yet). On the second redirect I lost the code parameter.

Comment: Hah, this was my issue, too.